# apache rewrite url for codeigniter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, uri, segments

I need to build app and i'm using codeigniter for this.
Company sends me a link in format that cant be changed from their side
Link is like:

```
someurl.com/sms.php?phone=12345678&msg=msg15&code=777&country=cc&oper=someoper& mssid=1234567892&notcharged=0&date=2011-12-26+23%3A31%3A27&keyword=msg&created=2011-12-26+23%3A31%3A26
```

How can i rewrite it with .htaccess so the codeigniter gets link in segmented format like

```
someurl.com/sms/myfunction/12345678/msg15/777/cc/someoper/1234567892/0/2011-12-26+23%3A31%3A27/msg/2011-12-26+23%3A31%3A26
```

Thanks

Edit.
Spent some hours and tried something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^phone\=([^&]+)\&msg\=([^&]+)\&code\=([^&]+)\&country\=([^&]+)\&oper\=([^&]+)\&mssid\=([^&]+)\&date\=([^&]+)\&keyword\=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /sms/doParse/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6/%7/%8 [R,L]
```

And then typing url like this:

```
http://test.airtel.lv/test.php?phone=12345678&msg=msg15&code=777&country=cc&oper=someoper&mssid=1234567892&date=2011-12-26+23%3A31%3A27&keyword=msg
```

I got this:

```
http://test.airtel.lv/sms/doParse/12345678/msg15/777/cc/someoper/1234567892/2011-12-26+23%253A31%253A27/msg?phone=12345678&msg=msg15&code=777&country=cc&oper=someoper&mssid=1234567892&date=2011-12-26+23%253A31%253A27&keyword=msg
```

Why returned url has GET params in the ending ?
And one more question, if that company will change and add extra param to link, the rewriting will be broken ? Then how can it be more universal ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this placing this in your .htaccess file in an appropriate place in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sms.php$ /sms/myfunction/ [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]+=([^&]+)&?(.*)
RewriteRule ^sms/myfunction/(.*)$ /sms/myfunction/$1/%1?%2 [L]
```

The first RewriteRule changes the `/sms.php` part of the URI to `/sms/myfunction/` and the second rule will append each **value** in your query string into its own part of the path. So a url like this: http://someurl/sms.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5&f=6&g=7&h=8&i=9 will have the URI internally rewritten to `/sms/myfunction/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9`. There's no checks on what the variable names are in the query string, only the value is extracted and appended to the URI path.

If you put that code in your server or vhost config (instead of an htaccess file) add a `/` in front of the `sms` in each of the rules so it says `^/sms` because rules in the htaccess have the leading slash stripped off when matching against the URI.

Comment: Tried to access

it returns The requested URL /sms/myfunction/12345678/msg15/777/cc/someoper/1234567892/11111/msg was not found.

CI uses link like http://sms.airtel.lv/index.php/sms/doParse and i cant access it without index.php

CI has "Enable query strings"
Maybe it will be better to rewrite url for query string like
sms.php?phone.... to sms.php?c=sms&m=doParse&phone=12345678&msg=msg15&code=777&country=cc&oper=someoper&mssid=1234567892&date=11111&keyword=msg
I just want to make if in link will be new param it wont brake my logic, cause in segments there are no GET names, only values

Answer (score 0):

just handle the GETs in your controller.  it's okay, GET isnt evil.

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
```

then you can have a simpler rewrite to handle the special route

Comment: I have link in format like
http://sms.airtel.lv/sms.php?phone=12345678&msg=msg15&code=777&country=cc&oper=someoper&mssid=1234567892&date=11111&keyword=msg

CI can parse link if it will be in format like

/sms.php?c=controller&m=method?phone=12345678.... and so on, i need to rewrite link and add to c=controller&m=method to start working with $_GET